# Spark YARN: Cannot allocate a page with more than 17179869176 bytes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am joining 11Mn records. I am running with 5 workers in EMR Cluster **Spark 2.2.1**

I am getting the following error while running the job:

```
executor 3): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot allocate a page with more than 17179869176 bytes
        at org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager.allocatePage(TaskMemoryManager.java:277)
        at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocateArray(MemoryConsumer.java:90)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.growPointerArrayIfNecessary(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:328)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.ShuffleExternalSorter.insertRecord(ShuffleExternalSorter.java:379)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.insertRecordIntoSorter(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:246)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.UnsafeShuffleWriter.write(UnsafeShuffleWriter.java:167)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am not able to understand the possible reason for this. Please help me with what parameter should I set.

Currently I am running with the following arguments: `--num-executors 5 --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --executor-memory 70g --driver-memory 30g --executor-cores 16  --conf spark.shuffle.memoryFraction=0.5`

Comment: What are the sizes of your cluster hosts in terms of memory?  What is your setting on YARN for `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`?

Comment: @tk421 it has 120gb memory. i didnt  set `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` parameter

Comment: Is 120GB per node or is it your total memory?